# How can I Estimate Table Sizes within Schema (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to estimate the table sizes within my schema (in MB). This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT table_name, owner, last_analyzed
FROM all_tables
```

I'm fairly new to SQL so I have no idea how I would go around doing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the "dba_segments" view (or user_segments if you don't have dba rights). The following query should give you what you're looking for:

```
select
  owner as "Schema"
  , segment_name as "Object Name"
  , segment_type as "Object Type"
  , round(bytes/1024/1024,2) as "Object Size (Mb)"
  , tablespace_name as "Tablespace"
from dba_segments
order by owner;
```

Comment: Hi Benoit, it worked perfectly thank you. I took a look at the table fields that I could be using, but I wasn't able to find "Owner" or last updated fields. By the way, I used the user_segments view. Would this information be available under dba_segments?

Comment: All segments shown in user_segments are owned by the account you used to log you on, that's why there's no owner column.

Comment: Correct prefix for 1024/1024 is `Mi` rather than `M` (see [Binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix))